# Side effects of nested for loops in batch file

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I created a prototype of the original problem, so this code is just to illustrate what I was facing.
(The original problem comes from an automatic build script.)

I iterate through 2 configurations and 2 architectures, so the body will be executed four times.
In this body I read a version number from an exe file, that will be included in a path later.

```
@echo off 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set targetDir=C:\TMP\OUTPUT

set configurations=RELEASE DEBUG
set architectures=X64 X86
for %%a in (%configurations%) do (
    set configuration=%%a
    for %%b in (%architectures%) do (
        set architecture=%%b
        echo Build !configuration! !architecture!
        set "notepadVersion="&for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%c in ('wmic datafile where "Name='c:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe'" get version /format:list') do set "notepadVersion=%%c"
        echo !notepadVersion!
        set destinationDir="%targetDir%\!notepadVersion! BETA !configuration! !architecture!"
        echo !destinationDir!
    )
)
```

When I execute this batch file, I got this output:

```
Build RELEASE X64
10.0.19041.1566
 BETA RELEASE X64"0.19041.1566
Build RELEASE X86
10.0.19041.1566
 BETA RELEASE X86"0.19041.1566
Build DEBUG X64
10.0.19041.1566
 BETA DEBUG X64"0.0.19041.1566
Build DEBUG X86
10.0.19041.1566
 BETA DEBUG X86"0.0.19041.1566
```

The correct output should be the following (the version number may differ on your machine):

```
Build RELEASE X64
10.0.19041.1566
C:\TMP\OUTPUT\10.0.19041.1566 BETA RELEASE X64
Build RELEASE X86
10.0.19041.1566
C:\TMP\OUTPUT\10.0.19041.1566 BETA RELEASE X86
Build DEBUG X64
10.0.19041.1566
C:\TMP\OUTPUT\10.0.19041.1566 BETA DEBUG X64
Build DEBUG X86
10.0.19041.1566
C:\TMP\OUTPUT\10.0.19041.1566 BETA DEBUG X86
```

What did I miss from the code?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's this ugly `wmic` line ending with an additional `CR` that gets part of the variable. Most robust way to get rid of it is another `for` loop: `set "notepadVersion="&for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%c in ('wmic datafile where "Name='c:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe'" get version /format:list') do for /f "delims=" %%d in ("%%c") do set "notepadVersion=%%d"`

Comment: Dear @Stephan, thank you it works :) I've updated the original post with your solution.

Comment: Don't do that. If there is no problem in the question, it isn't a question anymore and will be downvoted. Leave the question and post an answer instead. Accept it after cooldown to mark the question as solved.

Comment: You may use my [wmiClass.bat program](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10384&p=66414#p66401) in the exact same way. For example: `wmiClass.bat datafile /where:"Name='c:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe'" version`

Comment: @Aacini: I used to use it that way, but it was a direct request to have everything in one file. (But thank you for your link.)